# Mongoose password hashing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am looking for a good way to save an Account to MongoDB using mongoose.

My problem is: The password is hashed asynchronously. A setter wont work here because it only works synchronous.

I thought about 2 ways:

- Create an instance of the model and save it in the callback of the
  hash function.
- Creating a pre hook on 'save'

Is there any good solution on this problem?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

The mongodb blog has an excellent post detailing how to implement user authentication.

http://blog.mongodb.org/post/32866457221/password-authentication-with-mongoose-part-1

The following is copied directly from the link above:

### User Model

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    bcrypt = require('bcrypt'),
    SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;
     
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } },
    password: { type: String, required: true }
});
     
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var user = this;

    // only hash the password if it has been modified (or is new)
    if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();

    // generate a salt
    bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function(err, salt) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        // hash the password using our new salt
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            // override the cleartext password with the hashed one
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
});
     
UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        cb(null, isMatch);
    });
};
     
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

### Usage

```js
var mongoose = require(mongoose),
    User = require('./user-model');
     
var connStr = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mongoose-bcrypt-test';
mongoose.connect(connStr, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB');
});
     
// create a user a new user
var testUser = new User({
    username: 'jmar777',
    password: 'Password123'
});
     
// save the user to database
testUser.save(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
    
// fetch the user and test password verification
User.findOne({ username: 'jmar777' }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) throw err;
     
    // test a matching password
    user.comparePassword('Password123', function(err, isMatch) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Password123:', isMatch); // -&gt; Password123: true
    });
     
    // test a failing password
    user.comparePassword('123Password', function(err, isMatch) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('123Password:', isMatch); // -&gt; 123Password: false
    });
});
```

Comment: Just a note for someone that might try and fail to do this with an 'update' (what I did initially), from the mongoose docs: Pre and post save() hooks are not executed on update(), findOneAndUpdate(), etc.

Comment: Correct. What you could do is a separate find() and then save() function?

Comment: This method only works in creation, when the user update password it will not be hashed

Comment: In the `comparePassword` step, how does bcrypt know what the salt is for this user?

Comment: Turns out the salt is stored in the resulting hash https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/749

Comment: To get this to work on updates, we just do, `pre("findOneAndUpdate"`, is it?

Answer (score 26):

For those who are willing to use ES6+ syntax can use this -

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { isEmail } = require('validator');

const { Schema } = mongoose;
const SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;

const schema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    validate: [isEmail, 'invalid email'],
    createIndexes: { unique: true },
  },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
});

schema.pre('save', async function save(next) {
  if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();
  try {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR);
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
    return next();
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
});

schema.methods.validatePassword = async function validatePassword(data) {
  return bcrypt.compare(data, this.password);
};

const Model = mongoose.model('User', schema);

module.exports = Model;
```

Comment: The `validatePassword(data)` is async but you are not awaiting anything.

Comment: @RubekJoshi it's not necessary to await for a process inside an async function. 

In this case the bcrypt.compare() is an asynchronous function and because it takes a standard Node callback, we can automatically convert to an async/await syntax and return the promised containing the result. The consumer of the function will need to await it to get the result out. 

Good question though!

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR - Typescript solution**

I have arrived here when I was looking for the same solution but using typescript. So for anyone interested in TS solution to the above problem, here is an example of what I ended up using.

imports && contants:

```
import mongoose, { Document, Schema, HookNextFunction } from 'mongoose';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

const HASH_ROUNDS = 10;
```

simple user interface and schema definition:

```
export interface IUser extends Document {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
    validatePassword(password: string): boolean;
}

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
});
```

user schema pre-save hook implementation

```
userSchema.pre('save', async function (next: HookNextFunction) {
    // here we need to retype 'this' because by default it is 
    // of type Document from which the 'IUser' interface is inheriting 
    // but the Document does not know about our password property
    const thisObj = this as IUser;

    if (!this.isModified('password')) {
        return next();
    }

    try {
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(HASH_ROUNDS);
        thisObj.password = await bcrypt.hash(thisObj.password, salt);
        return next();
    } catch (e) {
        return next(e);
    }
});
```

password validation method

```
userSchema.methods.validatePassword = async function (pass: string) {
    return bcrypt.compare(pass, this.password);
};
```

and the default export

```
export default mongoose.model<IUser>('User', userSchema);
```

note: don't forget to install type packages (`@types/mongoose`, `@types/bcryptjs`)

Comment: `UserSchema.pre<DIUser>` work fine, also we can use 'bcrypt'  for performance.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a good way by user Mongoose and bcrypt！

#### User Model

```
/**
 * Module dependences
*/

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;

// define User Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        index: {
            unique: true
        }
    },
    hashed_password: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    }
});

// Virtuals
UserSchema
    .virtual('password')
    // set methods
    .set(function (password) {
        this._password = password;
    });

UserSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
    // store reference
    const user = this;
    if (user._password === undefined) {
        return next();
    }
    bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function (err, salt) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        // hash the password using our new salt
        bcrypt.hash(user._password, salt, function (err, hash) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            user.hashed_password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
});

/**
 * Methods
*/
UserSchema.methods = {
    comparePassword: function(candidatePassword, cb) {
        bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
            if (err) return cb(err);
            cb(null, isMatch);
        });
    };
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

#### Usage

```
signup: (req, res) => {
    let newUser = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    });
    // save user
    newUser.save((err, user) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(user);
    });
}
```

#### Result

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVdO6.png)

Answer (score 2):

The Mongoose official solution requires the model to be saved before using the verifyPass method, which can cause confusion. Would the following work for you? (I am using scrypt instead of bcrypt).

```
userSchema.virtual('pass').set(function(password) {
    this._password = password;
});

userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    if (this._password === undefined)
        return next();

    var pwBuf = new Buffer(this._password);
    var params = scrypt.params(0.1);
    scrypt.hash(pwBuf, params, function(err, hash) {
        if (err)
            return next(err);
        this.pwHash = hash;
        next();
    });
});

userSchema.methods.verifyPass = function(password, cb) {
    if (this._password !== undefined)
        return cb(null, this._password === password);

    var pwBuf = new Buffer(password);
    scrypt.verify(this.pwHash, pwBuf, function(err, isMatch) {
        return cb(null, !err && isMatch);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this using virtuals and instance methods:

```
/**
 * Virtuals
 */
schema.virtual('clean_password')
    .set(function(clean_password) {
        this._password = clean_password;
        this.password = this.encryptPassword(clean_password);
    })
    .get(function() {
        return this._password;
    });

schema.methods = {

    /**
     * Authenticate - check if the passwords are the same
     *
     * @param {String} plainText
     * @return {Boolean}
     * @api public
     */
    authenticate: function(plainPassword) {
        return bcrypt.compareSync(plainPassword, this.password);
    },

    /**
     * Encrypt password
     *
     * @param {String} password
     * @return {String}
     * @api public
     */
    encryptPassword: function(password) {
        if (!password)
            return '';

        return bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);
    }
};
```

Just save your model like, the virtual will do its job.

```
var user = {
    username: "admin",
    clean_password: "qwerty"
}

User.create(user, function(err,doc){});
```

Comment: A couple of questions on this - won't using bcrypt's synchronous methods block execution on the server until complete (so could cause performance issues for concurrent user access)? And also, what is the "this._password" used for? Does that become part of the schema?

Comment: @Jools your right about blocking execution, instead use the async method, and this._password its a temp var for the virtual, as per doc: "In Mongoose, a virtual is a property that is not stored in MongoDB. Virtuals are typically used for computed properties on documents" so it wont be stored.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const saltRounds = 5;
const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(saltRounds);

module.exports = (password) => {
  return bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);
}
```

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const hashPassword = require('../helpers/hashPassword')

const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: {
    type: String,
    match: [/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/, `Please fill valid email address`],
    validate: {
      validator: function() {
        return new Promise((res, rej) =>{
          User.findOne({email: this.email, _id: {$ne: this._id}})
              .then(data => {
                  if(data) {
                      res(false)
                  } else {
                      res(true)
                  }
              })
              .catch(err => {
                  res(false)
              })
        })
      }, message: 'Email Already Taken'
    }
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Password required']
  }
});

userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  if (this.password) {
      this.password = hashPassword(this.password)
  }
  next()
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

module.exports = User
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;

const userDataModal = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required : true,
        unique:true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required : true
    }

});

userDataModal.pre('save', function(next) {
    var user = this;

    // only hash the password if it has been modified (or is new)
    if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();

    // generate a salt
    bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function(err, salt) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        // hash the password using our new salt
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {
            if (err) return next(err);

            // override the cleartext password with the hashed one
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
});

userDataModal.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        cb(null, isMatch);
    });
};


// Users.index({ emaiId: "emaiId", fname : "fname", lname: "lname" });

const userDatamodal = module.exports = mongoose.model("usertemplates" , userDataModal)



//inserting document
     userDataModel.findOne({ username: reqData.username }).then(doc => {
            console.log(doc)
            if (doc == null) {
                let userDataMode = new userDataModel(reqData);
               // userDataMode.password = userDataMode.generateHash(reqData.password);
                userDataMode.save({new:true}).then(data=>{
                          let obj={
                              success:true,
                              message: "New user registered successfully",
                              data:data
                          }
                            resolve(obj)
                }).catch(err=>{
                                reject(err)
                })

            }
            else {
                resolve({
                    success: true,
                    docExists: true,
                    message: "already user registered",
                    data: doc
                }
                )
            }

        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
            reject(err)
        })

//retriving and checking
      // test a matching password
                user.comparePassword(requestData.password, function(err, isMatch) {
                    if (err){ 

                        reject({
                            'status': 'Error',
                            'data': err
                        });

                        throw err;
                    } else  {
                        if(isMatch){

                            resolve({   
                                'status': true,
                                'data': user,
                                'loginStatus' : "successfully Login"
                            });

                            console.log('Password123:', isMatch); // -&gt; Password123: true

                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be better to use the hook, after some research i found

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

where it says:

Use Cases:

asynchronous defaults

I prefer this solution because i can encapsulate this and ensure that an account can only be saved with a password.

Answer (score 0):

I used `.find({email})` instead of `.findOne({email}`).

Make sure to use `.findOne(...)` to get a user.

Example:

```
const user = await <user>.findOne({ email });
```