# Mongoose schema methods

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I have a mongoose schema method that i want to use on my new user instance creation (Before i save a new user,i want to set the password using the function **setPassword()**), i tried using '**this**' but it gives me a 'TypeError : undefined is not a function', i am new to mongoose. Here is my code

```
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('../models/user.js');

exports.signUpUser = function(req,res){

var newUser = new User({
    "name" : req.body.name,
    "surname" : req.body.surname,
    "username" : req.body.username,
    "password" : this.setPassword(req.body.password),
    "email" : req.body.email,
    "bank" : req.body.bank,
    "account_holder" : req.body.accountHolder,
    "account_number" : req.body.accountNumber 
});
```

Comment: Please check similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588032/mongoose-password-hashing

Comment: `setPassword` obviously has to be defined first. The question linked to by @AlexanderSuvorov is a good starting point.

Comment: The setPassword function is defined in the schema model that is in the module i required in User,but thanks anyway