# Mongoose virtuals: validation error after setter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

```
const User = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    hashedPassword: { type: String, required: true },
  }
)
```

I create the virtual field for hashing value before saving.

```
User.virtual('password')
  .get(function () { return this.hashedPassword })
  .set(function (password) {
    bcrypt.hash(password, 10)
      .then((hash) => {
        this.hashedPassword = hash
      })
  })
```

If I send query (body) I receive the error

```
// Query
User.create(req.body)
    .then((newUser) => {
....

// Body
{
  "email": "email@email.com",
  "password": "Test12345"
}

// Response
{
    "errors": {
        "hashedPassword": {
            "message": "Path `hashedPassword` is required.",
            "name": "ValidatorError",
...
```

I found the following information in the documentation for mongoose: Virtual property setters are applied before other validation.

Where is my error?

Comment: If I remember correctly you cannot use async code in setters and getters. Try using hashSync

Comment: Good day, I recommend using pre.save() in this case like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588032/mongoose-password-hashing) answer

Comment: @EvgeniyGrabelsky pre.save() not support findOneAndUpdate() and similar methods.