# How to compare salted/hashed passwords from database correctly?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bcrypt

I've seen this asked before but in other languages (C# and PHP) but I am working through Javascript. I am storing a username and password onto my database but the password is being hashed via bcrypt.

I can store it correctly but I cannot pull it from my database and compare it correctly. It always console logs my 'password does not match' message.

This is my registration code that stores the username and password onto my database.

```
app.post('/register', function (req, res) {
  var usernameCollection = mongoDBDatabase.collection('accounts');
  username = req.body.username;
  bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, saltRounds, function (err, hash) {
    usernameCollection.insertOne({
      personId: req.body.username,
      username: req.body.username,
      password: hash
    }).then(function(data) {
    if (data) {
   //res.redirect('/' + username);
   //window.location.href = "/" + username;
    }
  });
 });
});
```

And here is my code where I am searching my database for the username and trying to compare the password to no avail.

```
//login page: storing and comparing email and password,and     redirecting to home page after login
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
  var usernameCollection = mongoDBDatabase.collection('accounts');
  var username = req.body.username;
  var enteredPassword = req.body.password;

  usernameCollection.findOne({
    $or:[
          { username: username}
        ]
    }).then(function(user){
      if (user) {
        console.log('That username was found in the database');

        bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, user.password, function(err, result){
          if(result == true){
              console.log('Password matches!');
              res.redirect('/' + username);
         }
          else{
            console.log('Password did not match');
            res.redirect('/');
          }
        });
      }
      else{
        console.log('The username ' + username + ' was NOT found in the database');
      }
    });
});
```

I just want to compare the stored password to the entered password and confirm they are the same to log the user in.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588032/mongoose-password-hashing

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this issue on a fresh Mongo install and a fresh NPM `mongodb` package. The only thing I can suspect is that somewhere in the chain the Bcrypt string is "interpreted" as it starts with `$` (Mongo loves dollars). Maybe try storing `'x'+hash` as the password and then compare `user.password.substr(1)`. (That's ugly, but just a way to prove this long shot theory... hopefully wrong.)

Comment: I saw that @AnthonyWinzlet but I am not using UserSchema and not really sure what that is!

Comment: @StockOverflaw you are simply a beast. There is zero way I would have thought about that and it worked.

Comment: Good thing you could spot the problem, however this means there's something wrong here that needs to be addressed: what if your users want to name themselves `"$up3rm4n"`? Since I couldn't reproduce the issue with a fresh install, IMO your first steps should be to ensure NPM package `mongodb` is up to date, check the behavior, then the same for Mongo itself. And if the error still happens, there has to be a third-party package involved (proxying Mongo? `mongoDBDatabase` not a pure `require('mongodb').MongoClient`?) Good luck, please keep us posted when you found out!

Comment: @StockOverflaw Dang, thank you a lot for your help!! I'm definitely going to get to the bottom of this and see what is going on!