# Mongoose.post route seems to only get called when there's an error, but when theres no error it doesn't get called

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, axios

My .post route seems to only work when there's an error, I have another .post route that works just fine, and they both are written the exact same way so I'm very confused as to why this is happening. If I don't fill in all the fields, I get a "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning" as expected, meaning it attempted the route, but if every field is entered correctly, nothing happens at all. Not even a console.log() happens, and it doesn't save the item.

Server

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

//Routes
const users = require("./routes/users");
const bugs = require("./routes/bugs");

const app = express();

//Bodyparser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

// DB Config

app.use("/api/users", users);
app.use("/api/bugs", bugs);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

mongoose route

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Users = require("../schemas/users_schema");

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const newUser = new Users({
    Firstname: req.body.Firstname,
    Lastname: req.body.Lastname,
    Email: req.body.Email,
    Password: req.body.Password,
    DOB: req.body.DOB
  });
  console.log(newUser);

  newUser.save().then(item => res.json(item));
  console.log("Account created");
});
```

axios request

```
export const addItem = item => dispatch => {
  axios.post("/api/users", item).then(res =>
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_ITEM,
      payload: res.data
    })
  );
};
```

HTML/JSX

```
 <form>
                      <div>
                        <div className="signUp">
                          <input
                            type="date"
                            className="form-control form-control-lg"
                            placeholder="Enter your date of birth..."
                            onChange={() => this.setDOB.bind(this)}
                            value={this.state.DOB}
                          />
                          <div className="sep" />
                          <input
                            type="email"
                            className="form-control form-control-lg"
                            placeholder="Enter your email..."
                            onChange={() => this.setEmail.bind(this)}
                            value={this.state.Email}
                          />
                          <div className="sep"></div>
                          <input
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control form-control-lg"
                            placeholder="Enter your first name..."
                            onChange={() => this.setFirstname.bind(this)}
                            value={this.state.Firstname}
                          />
                          <div className="sep"></div>
                          <input
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control form-control-lg"
                            placeholder="Enter your last name..."
                            onChange={() => this.setLastname.bind(this)}
                            value={this.state.Lastname}
                          />

                          <div className="sep" />
                          <input
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control form-control-lg"
                            placeholder="Create your password..."
                            onChange={() => this.setPassword.bind(this)}
                            value={this.state.Password}
                          />
                          <button
                            className="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary"
                            onClick={() => {
                              const newUser = {
                                Firstname: this.state.Firstname,
                                Lastname: this.state.Lastname,
                                Email: this.state.Email,
                                Password: this.state.Password,
                                DOB: this.state.DOB
                              };
                              this.props.addItem(newUser);
                            }}
                          >
                            Sign up!
                          </button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="sep" />
                      </div>
                    </form>
```

Javascript setting the values

```
  setDOB = e => {
    this.setState({ DOB: e.target.value });
  };
  setEmail = e => {
    this.setState({ Email: e.target.value });
  };
  setFirstname = e => {
    this.setState({ Firstname: e.target.value });
  };
  setLastname = e => {
    this.setState({ Lastname: e.target.value });
  };
  setPassword = e => {
    this.setState({ Password: e.target.value });
  };
```

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const bcrypt = require("bcrypt"),
  SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema

const Users = new Schema({
  Firstname: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  Lastname: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  Email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  Password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  DOB: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  },
  GroupID: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    default: "NOGROUP"
  }
});

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588032/mongoose-password-hashing

Users.pre("save", function(next) {
  var user = this;

  // only hash the password if it has been modified (or is new)
  if (!user.isModified("Password")) return next();

  // generate a salt
  bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    // hash the password using our new salt
    bcrypt.hash(user.Password, salt, function(err, hash) {
      if (err) return next(err);

      // override the cleartext password with the hashed one
      user.Password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});

Users.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.Password, function(err, isMatch) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    cb(null, isMatch);
  });
};

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("Users", Users);
```

Comment: Can you post how are you using the `router`? like where are you import/require-ing the router? Basically your express server file where you added the routes.

Comment: Yes! Just updated it.

Comment: It looks ok to me, so in the schemas file, did you actually made a Model out of the schemas? I have encountered problems with mongoose where it just gets stuck no outputs no nothing. So one thing you can do is in the `router.post` comment out everything and just add a `res.json` or something and see if it is working

Comment: @AritraChakraborty I just added the schema if you want to take a look at it, it's just strange to me that not even the console.logs are even getting called. If anything works it should be that right?

Comment: I was able to figure it out, I realized my axios eventually stopped being called, and by default I guess a button re loads the page. So it was reloading the page before it even called my Axios request, so I added ```e.preventDefault();``` before I even set the newUser and it worked.