# Why bcrypt doesn't store the hash to DB?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js, bcrypt

I can't store my hashed password to MongoDB, and I even know "why"
The strangest thing it's all data that was passed by the client stored successfully except for the password hash from bcrypt. 
I tried using [this variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588032/mongoose-password-hashing) but It doesn't work for me.
Also, I want to present to you my variant (more simple, but it works, except of password hash of course):

```js
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {
  switch (req.method) {
    case "POST":
      try {
        const { name, email, password } = req.body;
        User.findOne({
          email,
        }).then(() => new Error("Error: User is already exist!"));

        bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, async function (err, hash) {
          if (err) throw Error("Error: Encryption error!");
          await User.create({
            name,
            email,
            password: hash,
          });
        });

        return res.status(201).json({ success: true });
      } catch (error) {
        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: error });
      }
  }
}
```

Also, I want to note that I didn't forget to modify user schema: `password: {type: String}`.

Comment: Make sure you are passing salt instead of saltRounds as integer to your brcypt.hash function..

Comment: @sms, I do as written in the documentation