# encrypt/decrypt password using bcryptjs in node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bcrypt, bcryptjs

I am trying to encrypt my password field i a registration form I created using bcryptjs but it isn't working

In mongodb, on post the data from the form, the password field shows the password entered in the form instead of encrypting it

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: `Name can't be empty`
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: `Username can't be empty`
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: `Email can't be empty`,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: `Password can't be empty`,
    minLength: [6, 'Password must be at least 6 character long']
  },
  saltSecret: String
});

userSchema.pre('save', (next)=>{
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt)=>{
    bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt, (err, hash)=>{
      this.password = hash;
      this.saltSecret = salt;
      next();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14595363/13211263

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the answer. I was using arrow function which doesn't have its own this binding. So I tried using the normal functions and it worked.
The modified code:

```
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var user = this;
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
      user.password = hash;
      user.saltSecret = salt;
      next();
    });
  });
});
```